# How can I split my node module down into additional files?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to split my node module functions into additional files as there are numerous functions I'm looking to add.

I would like to call the main file's functions into files loaded from lib and be able to call the lib functions directly, see:

In my main file `index.js`:

```
function Api(opt) {
  // set options
}

Api.prototype.get = function (endpoint) {
  return this.request('GET', endpoint, null);
};

Api.prototype.Catalog = require('./lib/catalog.js');

module.exports = Api;
```

Then in `lib/catalog.js`

```
function Catalog () {};

Catalog.prototype.getCategories = function () {
    return Api.get('categories');
}

module.exports = Catalog;
```

Then I'm hoping to achieve the following when the module is required, so the Catalog file will give access to :

```
var Module = require('module');

api = new Module({
    url: 'http://example.com', // without trailing slash
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password'
});

api.Catalog.getCategories();
```

When doing it this way I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCategories' of undefined
```

Is there a recommended way to achieve this or perhaps splitting it down into multiple node modules?

Comment: you need to add a require for them to be available before you make the call.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding require for the new modules

```
var Module = require('module');
var Catalog = require('Catalog');
var Api = require('Api');

api = new Module({
    url: 'http://example.com', // without trailing slash
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password'
});

api.Catalog.getCategories();
```

Comment: That wouldn't load them from lib though, they would need to be split into separate modules for Api and Catalog? The `var Module = require('module');` was meant to show the loading of the `index.js` file to load the Api functions, in your example it's split out?